# PHP getimagesize with variable

Tags: php, getimagesize

I'm trying to use the `getimagesize` function to get the height and with of an image. I'm pulling the image URL from a database. (The field `ProjectURL` contains a line such as `xxx.jpg`). However I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
$testing = "projects/'.$row['ProjectURL'].'";
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($testing);
    echo "Image width " .$width;
echo "<br />";
echo "Image height " .$height;
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting
>   T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Your first `'` should be a `"`. Use a decent IDE or editor with syntax highlighting, it will make finding such errors much easier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's because you are mixing single and double quotes...

this should be ok:

```
$testing = "projects/" . $row['ProjectURL'];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($testing);
echo "Image width " . $width;
echo "Image height " . $height;
```

You might also have noticed that I removed the *echo "";*... this one was useless :)

Comment: echo "<br />"; is not useless , otherwise it echoes them on the same line :) the better approach would be echo "Image width " . $width. "\n";

Comment: Last time I saw the article, there was no "<br />" but a \n... :)

Comment: Thanks very much Paul, it was the mixture of quotes. Working now, cheers :D