# How to access variables from php's list function

Tags: php, list, error-handling, resolution, getimagesize

I want to get the width value of an image using "getimagesize", but php doesn't seem to get the variables from the function's array through the "list" function.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
echo $width;
```

i get $width as undefined.

What might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the path to `$file` is correct and is an image?

Comment: what is in $file? is it accessible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4742105/ as an example. So, it could be your path.

Comment: Yes, the file is accessible, I'm viewing the $file after these lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("http://hdnewwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Green-Eyes-Girls.jpg");
echo $width;
echo "<br />";
echo $height;
?>
```

and result is

1024
682